# DirectShow IMediaSeeking position always return 0

Tags: c#, directshow

This is work good, I get compress video

```
     (graph as IMediaFilter).SetSyncSource(null).Check();
                        IMediaControl mc = graph as IMediaControl;
                        mc.Run().Check();
```

But this IMediaSeeking position always return 0. Why?

```
(graph as IMediaFilter).SetSyncSource(null).Check();
IMediaControl mc = graph as IMediaControl;
IMediaSeeking ms = mux as IMediaSeeking;
mc.Run().Check();

long length;
ms.GetDuration(out length).Check();
long pos;
while (ms.GetCurrentPosition(out pos).Succeeded() && pos < length)
{
    //this pos always 0
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this `IMediaSeeking` implementation (on this multiplexer filter) is not reporting position, or it does not report it correctly.

Comment: Why? This is all standart
gb.SetOutputFileName(DShowIDs.MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,
               dest_file, out mux, out sink).Check();
 gb.RenderStream(null, null, overlay_filter, compressor, mux).Check();

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation for [IMediaSeeking::GetCurrentPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd407028(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The Filter Graph Manager calculates the position from the current stream time; it does not query the filters in the graph. For file playback, this yields an accurate result, because playback is synchronized to the stream time. For file writing, the results are not accurate. To get the current position in a file-writing graph, query the multiplexer filter. (Position is not relevant for live capture, however.)

What is your renderer filter? Are you rendering to a file? If so you need to query the multiplexer filter.

You probably know this already but you shouldn't be using current position logic to decide whether the graph is finished yet - you need to wait for the EC_COMPLETE event (for example).

Comment: He's doing `mux as IMediaSeeking;`, that is multiplexer is used, which is about right/understandable, however he'd be interested to get more details, graph topology in particular. Maybe it's mux specific issue.